# Visual Studio 2022 Android Emulator Crashes on Startup

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, android-emulator, windows-11

I have a problem. Every time I try to debug an application with the default Android Emulator of VS 2022, it doesn't start, but crashes on startup [crash image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dApT2.png). Instead if I launch it manually the emulator starts but the phone displays a black screen. I tried turning Hyper-V on and off, I have reinstalled Visual Studio and and I checked the integrity of the files but it keeps crashing. This happened when I switched from Windows 10 to 11. With the 10 it worked fine. Any idea on what I can do? Thanks!